# addCleanup vs tearDown

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Recently, Ned Batchelder during [his talk at PyCon 2016](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/machete.html) noted:

> If you are using `unittest` to write your tests, definitely use
>   `addCleanup`, it's much better than `tearDown`.

Up until now, I've never used `addCleanup()` and got used to `setUp()`/`tearDown()` pair of methods for test "set up" and "tear down" phases.

Why should I switch to `addCleanup()` instead of `tearDown()`?

---

It was also recently discussed in the [Python unittest with Robert Collins](http://pythontesting.net/podcast/19-python-unittest-robert-collins/) podcast.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Per the [`addCleanup` doc string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup):

> Cleanup items are called even if setUp fails (unlike tearDown)

`addCleanup` can be used to register multiple functions, so you could use
separate functions for each resource you wish to clean up. That would allow your
code to be a bit more reusable/modular.

Answer (score 6):

`addCleanup()` methods will run even if one of them fails, and will run even if `setUp()` fails. You should also consider using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/).

Answer (score 4):

Another good thing about `addCleanup` is that it just works as you'd expect.

For example, if you call it in a `setUp` function, then all test methods will call the cleanup function in the end.

If you call it in a test method, only this method calls the cleanup function.